# Lotus Notes Custom Form

Tags: lotus-notes

I was given the task of creating a custom form in lotus notes and need some help please. The form is a simple auto fill style form that pulls data from other forms in Lotus notes. I was able to figure out how to do most of it however I can not figure out the last part. There is three forms that are completed at the time a customer purchases a car. The first form is called CUSTOMER, the second form is called VEHICLE and the third form is called HISTORY. My custom form is created by clicking "new form". The new form will pull the customer's name, phone number and address from the CUSTOMER form and auto fills it in on the new form. The problem is retrieving the information from the VEHICLE and HISTORY forms. I think the problem is that I do not know how to type the path correctly. If I am under the CUSTOMER form and type LASTNAME in the new form it will take the last name from the CUSTOMER form and auto fill it on the new form where I have typed [LASTNAME]. But what do I type to tell the new form to retrieve information from the form called VEHICLE and the field in the same form called LastName.  Any input will be very much appreciated

Comment: You may want to format your text and make the question clear, at the moment it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: downvoted because of readability. Please structure your question a bit. There is no chance to follow this text as it is.

Comment: Additional Info: PLEASE try to distinguish between FORM = Design element and DOCUMENT = Data created using a FORM. That might make it even clearer for yourself. There is ONE Customer FORM, but many Customer DOCUMENTS.

Comment: I managed to get through the poor formatting and incorrect use of "form" to refer to both forms and documents. :-( Anyhow, he's trying to inherit values from multiple documents into his new document. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your new form has the property set so that new documents will inherit values from their parent. If a document created with the CUSTOMER form is the parent (because that's what you had selected when you clicked to create a new document with your new form), LastName is inherited from the parent document in the new document. That's what allows you access it.  The two other documents (one with the VEHICLE form and one with the HISTORY form) are not the parent of your new document. You can't inherit from them.

You will have to learn to use the @DbLookup function in order to get values from those documents, and you will need to have (a) a key value that exists in those documents that you can use when doing the lookup, and (b) a view (or two views) that contains the VEHICLE and HISTORY documents and has the key value in the first sorted column.

Comment: Thank you, It took a few days of reading and searching but your answer helped me 100%. I have it working now and wanted to say thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to help. BTW, here on StackOverflow, the best way to thank me is by clicking to upvote and clicking to accept my answer.